# How can I use the variable {server.name} in services-config.xml from AIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, amf

I am converting an application from Flex/Flash to Flex/AIR. The application does messaging. I use the services-config.xml file to define channels & endpoints.

When using the endpoint definition in the services-config.xml I typically use;

```
  <channels>
    <channel-definition id="my-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
        <endpoint uri="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/Gateway.aspx" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
      <properties>
        <!-- <legacy-collection>true</legacy-collection> -->
      </properties>
    </channel-definition>
    <channel-definition id="my-rtmp" class="mx.messaging.channels.RTMPChannel">
        <endpoint uri="rtmp://{server.name}:1935" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.RTMPEndpoint"/>
    </channel-definition>
  </channels>
```

When running in AIR this is translated to the name of the SWF file (minus the first character oddly). I need to define at runtime the name of the server.

I have tried the following code in my creation complete section of the application;

```
RootDomain = "http://192.168.144.190/";
if (bolTestMode == false) 
{
    var strRTMPuri:String = RootDomain.substr(0, RootDomain.length - 1) + ":1935";
    strRTMPuri = strRTMPuri.toLowerCase().replace("http:","rtmp:");
    ServerConfig.getChannel("my-rtmp").uri = strRTMPuri;
    ServerConfig.getChannel("my-amf").uri = RootDomain.substr(0, RootDomain.length - 1) + ":80";
}
```

Which does not seem to work.

The only thing which does seem to work is changing the services-confg.xml file to;

```
  <channels>
    <channel-definition id="my-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
      <endpoint uri="http://192.168.144.190:{server.port}/Gateway.aspx" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
      <properties>
        <!-- <legacy-collection>true</legacy-collection> -->
      </properties>
    </channel-definition>
    <channel-definition id="my-rtmp" class="mx.messaging.channels.RTMPChannel">
     <endpoint uri="rtmp://192.168.144.190:1935" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.RTMPEndpoint"/>
    </channel-definition>
  </channels>
```

and then compiling the application. Unfortunately this means that the production version of the application will need to be compiled with a different services-config.xml file, from testing.

What i am looking for/need is a method to define the server & ports at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I was almost there when I posted the question, but I forgot a little piece.

The way I resolved it is by modifying the ServerConfig at runtime using using this in my Action Script.

```
ServerConfig.getChannel("my-amf").uri = "http://Myserver.com:80/gateway,aspx";
ServerConfig.getChannel("my-rtmp").uri = "http://Myserver.com:1935";
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but when I try this solution the application seems to ignore what I set on getChannel and still communicates to the server specified on services-confg.xml . I still don't know what to do.